# Return a print function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I return a print function in Python 2.7? In Python 3 you can type `return print(True)`, but in Python 2.7 I get an invalid syntax error when I try `return print True`. I'm new to Python.

Comment: Why do you want to return a print function?

Comment: Try parenthesis: ``return (print True)``

Comment: I just want to! I thought it was interesting that it was possible in python3 but I have no idea how to implement that in python2.7 and return (print True) does not work

Comment: You're not actually returning the `print` function in 3.x; you're returning the _result_ of calling the `print` function, which is always just `None`.

Comment: @abarnert is correct. If you want to return the print function, it will simply be `return print` (but that would not work in Python 2.x)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2.x `print` is not a function, but a keyword. 
The possible best solution would be importing 3.x-like print behvaiour as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function

p = print         # now you can store the function reference to a variable
p('I am a function now!')

>>> I am a function now!

def get_print():
    return print   # or return it :)

get_print()

>>> <function print>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible with Python 2.7 because print is not a function, it is a reserved word*. You can easily make a function for it just like this:

```
def printf(x):
  print x
```

And then you can do what you wish:

```
return (printf(True))
```

But you have to do that renaming.

*That's one of the things that were solved more elegantly on python 3.

Answer (score 0):

`print`, being a statement rather than a function in Python 2, cannot be used in this way. Rather, you need to do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def foo():
    return print(True)
foo()
```

Comment: Why `True` in `print(True)`? oO

Comment: @BasicWolf Cause that was in the original question

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. Time for me to go to bed :)